# First order PDE $u_t - u^2u_x = 0$ with piecewise initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

I have an initial value problem:

$$
u_t - u^2u_x = 0 \quad \text{with} \quad u(x,0) = g(x) = \begin{cases} 
         -\frac{1}{2}, & x\leq 0 \\
         1, & 0 < x <1 \\
         \frac{1}{2}, & x \geq 1 
         \end{cases}
$$

The characteristic system is

\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau} = 1, \hspace{30pt} \frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau} = -u^2, \hspace{30pt} \frac{\partial u}{\partial\tau} = 0
\end{align*}

with the initial curve given by
\begin{align*}
t(0) = 0, \hspace{30pt} x(0)=\xi, \hspace{30pt} u(0)=g(\xi)
\end{align*}
Note here that $u_{\tau}=0$ implies that the solution will be constant along the characteristics, and the characteristics will be straight lines. We have,
\begin{align*}
t = \tau, \hspace{30pt} u = \xi, \hspace{30pt} x = \xi-g(\xi)^2\tau
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
x = \begin{cases} 
\xi - \frac{\tau}{4}, & \xi\leq 0 \\
\xi - \tau, & 0 < \xi <1 \\
\xi - \frac{\tau}{4}, & \xi \geq 1 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Therefore the base characteristics are,
\begin{align*}
x &= \xi_0-\frac{\tau}{4} \hspace{10pt} \text{for } \xi_0 \leq 0 \\
x &= \xi_0-\tau \hspace{10pt} \text{for } 0\leq\xi_0 \geq 1 \\
x &= \xi_0-\frac{\tau}{4} \hspace{10pt} \text{for } \xi_0 \geq 1 
\end{align*}

I can plot the base characteristics no problem, and I know that there are missing characteristics. **My problem is finding them**. I get,
$$
u(x,t) = g(\xi) = \begin{cases} 
         -\frac{1}{2}, & x\leq -\frac{t}{4} \\
         1, & -t < x <1-t \\
         \frac{1}{2}, & x \geq 1-\frac{t}{4} 
         \end{cases}
$$

First of all, I can get my missing characteristics for $1-t<x<1-\frac{t}{4}$. Also my cases overlap, so I know $u(x,t)$ will be multivalued, but finding these missing characteristics is proving trouble some. Any ideas would be appreciated.